# Excel Match Index for Mutliple Criteria in one cell

Tags: excel, sharepoint, excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet which is filled automatically from data in Microsoft Sharepoint. Unfortunately this data fills my location column as follows: IND;# ENG ;# USA if for example that particular input has 3 locations.

I then have drop down boxes (made via data validation) to filter the results down and give an optimum result. However when it comes to choosing location i can either choose ALL, IND, ENG, USA OR IND;# ENG ;# USA. If I chose, for instance, IND, then the options that are in multiple locations will not be returned (only the options that are in only IND will).

I was just wondering if there is any way, avoiding VBA, which will enable a choice of the individual location to return all options in this location, including the options that are availible in multiple locations.

** Please note that these multiple locations are contained within the SAME cell.

Comment: Are ENG USA and IND the only 3 locations you have, or are there many more?

Comment: You could filter your column where the cell CONTAINS "IND" or "ENG" for example.

Comment: I need the spreadsheet to be automatic, so a user can update it via their sharepoint data and the rest will just flow. I can't generate an automatic filter without using VBA and I am trying to refrain from VBA for the benefit of the user.

Comment: As it stands there are 4 locations, or a mix of these 4. The user's data will influence this but I am assuming there to be at maximum only another couple of locations.

Comment: Its a very good question, and for the moment, I am stumped!  The only way I can think of doing it would be to have a column for each location, and you filter by the column you want.  That isn't ideal however.  The fact is, if you want to automate this, you either need to code it in VBA, or use something that is built for the purpose.  For example, you could store your raw data in an Access table, and create a query that shows the data by location based on the person accessing.  Not easy to relay how to do this, unless you have Access experience?

Comment: I would rather not use Access, I simply need to give a completed excel programme to the user which they will have automatically updated from their sharepoint data. The rest is expected to flow simply by the choices made in the drop down box. Is there no way to excel to identify a string of three letters i.e. BRZ and search for that, rather than the entire list? Therefore performing INDEX/MATCH for a small section of the location

Comment: Hey, or even a wildcard? /:

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as you have the question written.  A drop down list created by data validation can only display a single result.  If you chose 'IND' and wanted to show results for say 'IND' and  'IND, ENG' you would need to use something other than a drop down list or you need to do additional filtering based on the value selected down stream in your code/logic.

I'd say your best bet is to use VBA.  This can be transparent from the user.  When a user selects a value in the drop down list, vba can sort and filter the remaining drop down list based on what was selected (aka dependent drop downs)