# Partial text INDEX/MATCH excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007

So I have a column where single cells have numerous data within  them. i.e. in A1 it says ABC;# DEF ;# GHI where ABC, DEF and GHI are all individual peices of data.

I am creating a dropdown box where this data is needed, but if there is multiple letter combinations in a single cell the drop down box takes this as one single peice of data rather than 2 or 3.

I want to create an INDEX/MATCH function which will find corresponding data to these letter combinations, also returning data where the the corresponding combination is in a cell with other combinations. i.e. dog ABC ;# DEF when i search DEF dog will be returned.

I am assuming I can do this with a wildcard? Am I correct or is there alternative, better, methods? Plus if it is done via a wildcard how do I write the formula

Comment: See [Excel Match Index for Mutliple Criteria in one cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868001/excel-match-index-for-mutliple-criteria-in-one-cell). Please do edit your question instead if it's about the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `MATCH` allows wildcards in the lookup value, so if you want to search column A for "DEF" within other text and return a value from column B use this formula

`=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("*DEF*",A:A,0))`

....or you can also use VLOOKUP if the lookup range is to the left of the return range, e.g.

`=VLOOKUP("*DEF*",A:B,2,0)`

If DEF is in a cell, e.g. D2 then you can replace "*DEF*" in either of those with "*"&D2&"*". Neither formula is case-sensitive